# declare -A in bash 3

Tags: bash

I have a script which requires index ordering based on the entry order of an associative variable and not typical bash ordering. Hence, as with bash 4, I use `declare -A var` and indeed, my ordering is maintained. However, this is not the case for bash 3.

Can anyone offer an alternative solution? Google is very unhelpful!

Kind regards

*edit* Since found that bash 3 doesn't even support associative arrays, so I'm trying `$options_$opt` but it does not process. Any solution similar to this would be appreciated.

Comment: So you want to simulate associative arrays in a bash version, which does not support them, correct? And I guess you can't switch to a different shell, such as `zsh` instead, or to a completely different language (Perl, Ruby,....)? How about doing it in `awk` then; this should be available.

Comment: Even when associative arrays are available, the perceived need for them is usually a good sign that it's time to stop writing a `bash` script and time to use a different language.

Comment: Fair comments. It's for a framework so accessibility over bash is essential. I'm working with a screen input script in bash which calls on PHP code. The answer I gave suffices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I used variable variables.

For assignment:
`declare $command="$description"`

Followed by
`${!key}`

This allows you to reference a "key" in the declare command. A bit of a hack, but, same thinking as associative arrays.